# Weak derivative: recursive definition, or confusing notation?

Tags: weak-derivatives

According to the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative), if $u$ and $v$ are locally integrable functions on some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $v$ is the weak derivative of $u$ if, for any infinitely differentiable function $\varphi$ on $U$ with compact support, we have
$$\int_U u D^{\alpha}\varphi = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int v\varphi,$$
where
$$D^{\alpha}\varphi = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}\varphi}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}.$$

They then go on to say that the weak derivative is often notated $D^{\alpha}u$. Replacing this in the above definition, we get

$$\int_U u D^{\alpha}\varphi = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int D^{\alpha}u \varphi.$$

Just checking my understanding here: $D^{\alpha}$ is used to signify two different things here, right? The one of $\varphi$ is a big partial derivative, while the one on $u$ denotes the weak derivative (i.e. a locally integrable function that satisfies that satisfies that identity). If so, is there no better notation that we can use? This looks terribly confusing.

Comment: It rarely happens that you need to distinguish between the various kinds of derivatives (strong, weak), so it would be much more confusing to have different symbols for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $D^{\alpha}u$ is a notation for the weak derivative that satisfies the "partial integration-equation" and $D^{\alpha}\varphi$ denotes the classical derivative which is of course a weak derivative too, because it satisfies

$\int_U\phi D^{\alpha}\psi=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_U D^{\alpha}\phi \psi$

for all smooth $\psi$ with compact support. So the notation is now understood as the weak derivative but is still consistent with that of a classical partial derivative. Even if it is confusing at the beginning it´s better to get used to it because it is used very often (cf. Evans Partial differential equations and many others).